# React Native run-android build fails

Tags: android, maven, react-native

I've followed the setup guide for react-native android on Mac OS X. I have the emulator running. When I run react-native run-android I get the following:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':app:_debugCompile'.
   > Could not find any matches for com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.+ as no versions of com.android.support:appcompat-v7 are available.
     Searched in the following locations:
         file:/Users/hugo/.m2/repository/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/maven-metadata.xml
         file:/Users/hugo/.m2/repository/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/
         https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/maven-metadata.xml
         https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/
     Required by:
         fuckoff:app:unspecified
   > Could not find com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0.
     Searched in the following locations:
         file:/Users/hugo/.m2/repository/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/22.2.0/appcompat-v7-22.2.0.pom
         file:/Users/hugo/.m2/repository/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/22.2.0/appcompat-v7-22.2.0.jar
         https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/22.2.0/appcompat-v7-22.2.0.pom
         https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/22.2.0/appcompat-v7-22.2.0.jar
     Required by:
         fuckoff:app:unspecified > com.facebook.react:react-native:0.11.0
   > Could not find com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.3.
     Searched in the following locations:
         file:/Users/hugo/.m2/repository/com/android/support/support-v4/21.0.3/support-v4-21.0.3.pom
         file:/Users/hugo/.m2/repository/com/android/support/support-v4/21.0.3/support-v4-21.0.3.jar
         https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/support-v4/21.0.3/support-v4-21.0.3.pom
         https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/support-v4/21.0.3/support-v4-21.0.3.jar
     Required by:
         fuckoff:app:unspecified > com.facebook.react:react-native:0.11.0 > com.facebook.fresco:fresco:0.6.1 > com.facebook.fresco:drawee:0.6.1
         fuckoff:app:unspecified > com.facebook.react:react-native:0.11.0 > com.facebook.fresco:fresco:0.6.1 > com.facebook.fresco:imagepipeline:0.6.1
```

I have all the necessary Android SDK packages installed including the build tools and the support repository. I'm noticing that it's looking for a directory in my home called `.m2`, which doesn't exist. I've never needed Maven to do android development. Do I need to install it to use react-native?

Comment: you probably do have a `.m2` directory. (it is not visible in finder with the default settings). It is were the support libraries are, under a maven repo, which is how gradle satisfies the `compile` dependencies (other dependencies are satisfied using online repos, like maven central, but android support is local).

Comment: you just need to update the support repository in the `SDK Tools` section.

Comment: @njzk2 I found the answer, I just can't accept it, but thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Just to be absolutely safe, I tried updating the android packages using `android update sdk --no-ui`.

Apparently the software I installed using `android` weren't the most up to date. Running the update fixed the issue.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Hugo. I've installed the repo from SDK manager but didn't work. Running the update command solved the issue!